# Getting Position of Element from Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, offset

I know I can use jQuery's `.position()` and `.offset()` but I don't know why they aren't working as described (relative to parent and relative to document, respectively).

I have these codes : <del>http://jsfiddle.net/ugxag1wg/1/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/ugxag1wg/3/

(same as jsfiddle) : Assuming I have 5 blocks and each block is 500px high and using the code below :

```
$(".block").each(function(){
    dist = $(this).position();

    $(this).data("distance", dist.top );

    $(this).text( $(this).data("distance") );
})
```

It works well if I load the page by itself. However, if I refresh it when I'm not at the top position (or load with anchor to one of the blocks below the top), I will not get 0 value for the first block. Instead, it will be negative of where I am looking.

For example, if I load the page fresh, I should get 0, 500, 1000, 1500 and 2000 for the blocks respectively, showing their offset from the top of the parent container. However, if I refresh the page halfway down (say, at 2nd block) or load with anchor to 2nd block, I will get -500, 0, 500, 1000, 1500 instead.

I have tried with both `.position()` and `.offset()` but had same result. So, what I want to know is, **how can I get the result in the first example, consistently, regardless of where the page is loaded?** Basically, I just want to know their position from the top of their parent container.

Thanks for helping!

**Edit :** I think I found the problem. I have another container (with 100vh height) wrapping the parent container of the blocks (see updated jsfiddle). So when I scrolled, it was the parent container which moved but the container wrapper didn't.

So, **why wasn't the position returned using `.position()` relative to the `.parent` element, but seems to be relative to the `.parent-container` element?** How should I solve the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that dist is a global variable the way you defined it. change to var dist. You are essentially overwriting it each time. :/

I also edited your fiddle. Keep in mind for body padding :)
http://jsfiddle.net/ugxag1wg/2/

```
 html, body{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;        
 }
```

This should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, it was a snippet from the original code. I did put var dist outside that function as a global variable (and also within), both producing same results (i.e. not working as intended). The variable is only used in this function, so I don't mind getting it overwritten each time instead of creating a new one. So, any ideas what else could be the problem, or alternative ways of achieving what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Does my fiddle not help?

Comment: There wasn't any changes to the JavaScript code right? (no difference that I could spot). I did reset the CSS styles in my actual website (but didn't do so in the fiddle), so I guess that's not the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question since I've found the cause of the problem. Any ideas how to solve that? One of the ways which I can think of is to have each of them deduct the `.position()` of `.parent`, but that doesn't sound too efficient to me.

Comment: .position() should do what your asking, so maybe it would be better to know what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but I don't know why it isn't behaving as such. Right now I'm saving the top position of first block as a variable and using it to deduct for every block to get what I wanted to achieve.